# How to clear PHP artisan cache for a single entry instead of everything

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Usually when I want to clear app cache I run `php artisan cache:clear` but that removes *all* cache entries. What I'm hoping to do is forget a single element from command line by specifying the key. For example, something like `php artisan cache:clear --key=userids`.

I looked through some documentation but couldn't find anything. Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no php artisan cache:clear --key=userids command that I am aware of but you can delete a particular cache using tinker. Just run

```
php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.10.8 (PHP 8.0.6 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> Cache::get('me');
=> "I am Sandeep"
>>> Cache::forget('me');
=> true
>>> Cache::get('me');
=> null
```

Answer (score 4):

Hop into the Laravel shell via `php artisan tinker`, and then type/paste `Cache::forget('userids');` in there.

If you find yourself needing to do this frequently, consider [a custom Artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with artisan:

`php artisan cache:forget {key}`